# Finding nested elements with XPath (same type)

Tags: xpath, nested

I can’t figure out how to find nested elements of the same type. Typically, if I have 7 levels of headers and want to transform them with XSLT to h1–h7 heads, how to choose them with XPath—I can’t make out nothing better than `div/div/div/head` but this seems really clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div/head">
      <xsl:element name="h{count(ancestor::div)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<div>
    <head>1</head>
    <div>
        <head>2-1</head>
        <div>
            <head>3-1</head>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <head>2-2</head>
    </div>
</div>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<div>
    <h1>1</h1>
    <div>
        <h2>2-1</h2>
        <div>
            <h3>3-1</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>2-2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, not so easy as I would have thought! Very interesting, thanks a lot.